# Css jquery.each just one do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a rookie when it comes to Javascript.

First thanks for all of your answers.

Please follow under codes.

I made like this.

- This is crawler htmls one section.

  ```
  <select data-js="career-select" data-group-id="stats">
      <option value="0x02E00000FFFFFFFF" option-id="ALL HEROES">ALL HEROES</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000002" option-id="Reaper">Reaper</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000003" option-id="Tracer">Tracer</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000004" option-id="Mercy">Mercy</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000005" option-id="Hanzo">Hanzo</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000006" option-id="Torbj&#xF6;rn">Torbj&#xF6;rn</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000007" option-id="Reinhardt">Reinhardt</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000008" option-id="Pharah">Pharah</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000009" option-id="Winston">Winston</option>
      <option value="0x02E000000000000A" option-id="Widowmaker">Widowmaker</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000015" option-id="Bastion">Bastion</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000016" option-id="Symmetra">Symmetra</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000020" option-id="Zenyatta">Zenyatta</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000029" option-id="Genji">Genji</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000040" option-id="Roadhog">Roadhog</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000042" option-id="McCree">McCree</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000065" option-id="Junkrat">Junkrat</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000068" option-id="Zarya">Zarya</option>
      <option value="0x02E000000000006E" option-id="Soldier: 76">Soldier: 76</option>
      <option value="0x02E0000000000079" option-id="L&#xFA;cio">L&#xFA;cio</option>
      <option value="0x02E000000000007A" option-id="D.Va">D.Va</option>
      <option value="0x02E00000000000DD" option-id="Mei">Mei</option>
      <option value="0x02E000000000012E" option-id="Sombra">Sombra</option>
      <option value="0x02E000000000013B" option-id="Ana">Ana</option>
  </select>
  ```
- This is server side jQuery part.

  ```
  var quick_data = $(`#quickplay select[data-group-id="stats"]`);
  quick_data.each(function() {
      var test= $(this).find("option").attr('value');
      console.log('test : ' + test);
   })
  ```

I tried and got values(like '0x230000000fffffffffff') but if I use server side jQuery send like this

```
test : 0x02E00000FFFFFFFF
```

Just 1.. just one!!

Why this just works one?

[image]

Thank you for read my foolish code and English

Thank you and Regards

Comment: because you select the first option?

Comment: @epascarello: To be fair, he's *selecting* all the options, but then `attr` just returns the value of the first element in the set. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this just works one?

Because there's only one `select`, so your `each` callback is called only once, and it grabs the value of the **first** option within it (because that's how `attr`, `val`, `prop`, and such work when you use them as getters*).

If you want each value, you can loop through the options:

```
$(`#quickplay select[data-group-id="stats"] option`).each(function(){
    console.log('test : ' + this.value);
});
```

Example:

```js
$(`#quickplay select[data-group-id="stats"] option`).each(function() {
  console.log('test : ' + this.value);
});
```

```html
<div id="quickplay"><select data-js="career-select" data-group-id="stats">
        <option value="0x02E00000FFFFFFFF" option-id="ALL HEROES">ALL HEROES</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000002" option-id="Reaper">Reaper</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000003" option-id="Tracer">Tracer</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000004" option-id="Mercy">Mercy</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000005" option-id="Hanzo">Hanzo</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000006" option-id="Torbj&#xF6;rn">Torbj&#xF6;rn</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000007" option-id="Reinhardt">Reinhardt</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000008" option-id="Pharah">Pharah</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000009" option-id="Winston">Winston</option>
        <option value="0x02E000000000000A" option-id="Widowmaker">Widowmaker</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000015" option-id="Bastion">Bastion</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000016" option-id="Symmetra">Symmetra</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000020" option-id="Zenyatta">Zenyatta</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000029" option-id="Genji">Genji</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000040" option-id="Roadhog">Roadhog</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000042" option-id="McCree">McCree</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000065" option-id="Junkrat">Junkrat</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000068" option-id="Zarya">Zarya</option>
        <option value="0x02E000000000006E" option-id="Soldier: 76">Soldier: 76</option>
        <option value="0x02E0000000000079" option-id="L&#xFA;cio">L&#xFA;cio</option>
        <option value="0x02E000000000007A" option-id="D.Va">D.Va</option>
        <option value="0x02E00000000000DD" option-id="Mei">Mei</option>
        <option value="0x02E000000000012E" option-id="Sombra">Sombra</option>
        <option value="0x02E000000000013B" option-id="Ana">Ana</option>
     </select></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

* jQuery is *set-based*. In your original code, `$(this).find("option")` returned a set of option elements (all of them), but when you use a *getter* on the set, it only gets from the first element in the set. (In contrast, jQuery's *setters* update all elements in the set; the API is assymmetrical.) There's one exception to this: `text`, when used as a getter, gets the text of *all* of the elements in the set. (I have no idea why it's different from all the others.)

Comment: Really Thank you i understand css jquery selector part because you.. really Thank you so much! always be happy!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your jQuery foreach has the wrong selector. You're doing foreach on the select, not the options with in the select. Try this

```
var quick_data = $(`#quickplay select[data-group-id="stats"] > option`);
```

Comment: Thank you your answer! this is simple and good working Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(`#quickplay select[data-group-id='stats'] option`)
```

This will grab all options under id quickplay where select has the attribute data-group-id stats.

vs.

```
$(`#quickplay select[data-group-id='stats']`)
```

This will grab all selects under #quickplay (with the data-group-id being stats).

Then you add:

```
.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("option").attr("value"));
});
```

And, now, we're iterating through all of our selects and printing the first
option.  When you use functions like .attr() on multiple elements,
it will take the value from only the first one.  It does not return an array.

```js
$(`#quickplay select[data-group-id='stats'] option`).each(function(){
 var test= $(this).attr('value');
 console.log('test : ' + test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quickplay">
 <select data-js="career-select" data-group-id="stats">
  <option value="0x02E00000FFFFFFFF" option-id="ALL HEROES">ALL HEROES</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000002" option-id="Reaper">Reaper</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000003" option-id="Tracer">Tracer</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000004" option-id="Mercy">Mercy</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000005" option-id="Hanzo">Hanzo</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000006" option-id="Torbj&#xF6;rn">Torbj&#xF6;rn</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000007" option-id="Reinhardt">Reinhardt</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000008" option-id="Pharah">Pharah</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000009" option-id="Winston">Winston</option>
  <option value="0x02E000000000000A" option-id="Widowmaker">Widowmaker</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000015" option-id="Bastion">Bastion</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000016" option-id="Symmetra">Symmetra</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000020" option-id="Zenyatta">Zenyatta</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000029" option-id="Genji">Genji</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000040" option-id="Roadhog">Roadhog</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000042" option-id="McCree">McCree</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000065" option-id="Junkrat">Junkrat</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000068" option-id="Zarya">Zarya</option>
  <option value="0x02E000000000006E" option-id="Soldier: 76">Soldier: 76</option>
  <option value="0x02E0000000000079" option-id="L&#xFA;cio">L&#xFA;cio</option>
  <option value="0x02E000000000007A" option-id="D.Va">D.Va</option>
  <option value="0x02E00000000000DD" option-id="Mei">Mei</option>
  <option value="0x02E000000000012E" option-id="Sombra">Sombra</option>
  <option value="0x02E000000000013B" option-id="Ana">Ana</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: First sorry for don't choice your answer.. but your answer is awesome.. really kind you! thank you really thank you!